# Service Causing Unexpected Close

Tags: java, android

I am creating a game app and I have a few activities for the different screens. I have a service I am using to play music through out the activities. A really simple service, I have the title screen with image buttons to turn it on and off. Now I am getting a unexpected close and this error message from eclipse:

```
[2011-05-19 19:50:04 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:571)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

EDIT: Code For Service

public class BGMusic extends Service {
    MediaPlayer player;

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.still_wana);
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onCreate();
    player.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.stop();
}
```

}

EDIT: Console Android Msg

Starting activity com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanTitle on device emulator-5554
ActivityManager: DDM dispatch reg wait timeout
ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 52454151: no handler defined
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.android.hitmanassault/.HitmanTitle }

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:571)
```

You have a null pointer problem at line 571 of Client.java.

Probably caused by passing a parameter that can't be null as null. Maybe this for example:

```
R.raw.still_wana
```

Comment: Thanks, where can I find that file at?

Comment: @Manji I have no idea. Showing us the code you are *calling it with* might get you somewhere.

Comment: in the question post I mean sorry.

Comment: I tried that I also edited the question to add some more information that I found out once I tried to re-do the code but I still get the same message. Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: I needed to re-do my xml file that was holding the buttons to start and stop the music.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong super method in `onStart()`:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onCreate();
```

It should be:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
```

Comment: Tried it, gives me an error and when I fix the error it still doesn't work.

Comment: Was the error because I left the arguments out of the super call (fixed now)? When you say _it still doesn't work_ what do you mean by that? Do you get the same error as in your question?

Comment: Yes, I tried just Googleing my question but I can't a definite answer so I might just rewrite the whole thing. I fixed the time out error that started to show up.

Comment: I needed to re-do my xml file that was holding the buttons to start and stop the music.